# Polymer 1.0 routing solutions?

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing, polymer-1.0

I'm building an app using Polymer 1.0 and I'm wondering what's my options with respect to routing ? I have seen more-routing but I don't know if it's compatible with 1.0, Is there a good stable declarative routing solution similar to more-routing if it's not supported ?

Answer (score 1):

Try app router:
https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router

I'm using it with 1.0 and it works well.
My routes are set up declaratively, and I trigger the routing imperatively using on-tap actions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Pages.js with Polymer 1.0 for client-side routing using the *hashbang* option.
eg.
http://localhost:8000/#!/home

[Watch the routing Polycast](http://youtu.be/iDQqP5Yyczg) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty neat, has some features like `nesting`,`query`,`params` it's under development but is very useful

**Easy-Router** -  http://customelements.io/MartinsThiago/easy-router

simple usage example

```
<page-admin path="#!/admin">
  //Content
</page-admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dna-router. You can create define states and routes in HTML only.

Setup routes by:

```
<dna-new-state state='home' route='/home'></dna-new-state>

<dna-new-state state='user' route='/user/:id/'></dna-new-state>
```

Create views by:

```
<dna-view state='home' element='home-template'></dna-view>
```

For a detailed documentation, visit : https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router